# Fastest way to find all paths in a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with multiple starting nodes?

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, graph-theory

I am trying to find all paths in a directed acyclic graph (DAG) with multiple starting nodes. I already have the DAG represented by a list of lists, **together with each level of nodes from starts to terminations**:

```
dag = [[4, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 7],
       [], [], [], [], [1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 2, 3]]
levels = [[8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
```

The example DAG colored by levels looks like this:
[image]

Since I have 3 starting nodes `[8, 9, 10]`, my first thought is performing 3 DFSs. Below is my code:

```
def get_all_paths(dag, sources):

    def dfs(data, path, paths=None):
        if paths is None:
            paths = []
        prev = path[-1]
        if data[prev]:
            for val in data[prev]:
                new_path = path + [val]
                paths = dfs(data, new_path, paths)
        else:
            paths += [path]
        return paths

    all_paths = []
    for i in sources:
        paths = dfs(data=dag, path=[i], paths=[])
        all_paths += paths

    return all_paths

all_paths = get_all_paths(dag, sources=levels[0])
print(all_paths)
```

Output:

```
[[8, 1, 5], [8, 1, 6], [8, 1, 7], [8, 3, 4], [8, 3, 5], [8, 3, 7], 
 [9, 1, 5], [9, 1, 6], [9, 1, 7], [9, 2, 4], [9, 2, 5], [9, 2, 6], 
 [10, 0, 4], [10, 0, 6], [10, 0, 7], [10, 2, 4], [10, 2, 5], 
 [10, 2, 6], [10, 3, 4], [10, 3, 5], [10, 3, 7]]

%timeit 24.6 µs ± 577 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

However, when the graph is large or there are many starting nodes, my code becomes very slow. As we all know, the DFS time complexity of finding all paths in a DAG `G(V,E)` is *O(V+E)*. So my approach has the time complexity of *O(m(V+E))*, where *m* is the number of starting nodes. In my code, each node is visited *m* times, but I feel like it is possible to still visit each node only once, especially given the `levels` and I'm not utilizing it. Maybe a BFS will do, but I'm not sure how to write it. Any suggestions?

### Edit

Here are some benchmarking of the answers

I have adjusted my BFS code based on @chepner's comment.

```
def get_all_paths(dag, sources):

    def dfs(data, path, paths=None):
        if paths is None:
            paths = []
        prev = path[-1]
        if data[prev]:
            for val in data[prev]:
                new_path = path + [val]
                paths = dfs(data, new_path, paths)
        else:
            paths.append(path[1:])

        return paths

    dag.append(sources)
    
    return dfs(data=dag, path=[len(dag)-1], paths=[])

%timeit get_all_paths(dag, sources=levels[0])
```

Output:

```
9.73 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Testing @aminrd's answer:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def aminrd(dag, levels):
    paths = defaultdict(list)
    levels_reversed = levels[::-1]

    for node in levels_reversed[0]:
        paths[node] = [[node]]

    for lvl in levels_reversed[1:]:
        for src in lvl:
            for dst in dag[src-1]:
                paths[src] += [[src] + p for p in paths[dst]]

    result = []
    for lvl_0 in levels[0]:
        result += paths[lvl_0]
        
%timeit aminrd(dag, levels)
```

Output

```
10.7 µs ± 164 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: "As we all know, the DFS time complexity of finding all paths in a DAG G(V,E) is O(V+E)." Where do we know that from? Number of paths in a DAG is exponential on the number of vertices.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Because DFS visits each vertex once and each edge twice?

Comment: This can only mean that DFS cannot find all paths in a DAG. There are too many of them.

Comment: Consider this graph `[[1,2],[2,3],...,[19,20],[20],[]]` with a single start vertex 0. There are 21 vertices, 39 edges, and fib(21)=10946 paths. Your program finds all of them, which means your assessment of its complexity is way off.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. OK. I think there is some misunderstanding here. I only want to get the shortest paths from sources to destinations. Given a graph that can be labelled by different levels, it must have all paths equal to shortest paths.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Note that it cannot have directed edges between nodes at a same level.

Comment: The number of shortest paths is still exponential. Consider this graph `[[2,3],[2,3],[4,5],[4,5],.....,[n,n+1],[n,n+1],[],[]]` with start vertices 0 and 1. There are n/2 levels and 2^(n/2) paths, all of same length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for paths in a single augmented graph. If your set of starting nodes is `S`, add a new starting node `S0` and edges `(S0, s)` for each `s` in `S`. Once your single DFS completes, you can simply remove `S0` from each path, leaving you with the paths in your original graph.

This may reduce some of the duplication created by running `dfs` multiple times, but won't address the unavoidable fact that your running time is proportional to the number of paths to be found.

Answer (score 2):

By starting from the nodes in the last level, you can create a hash so that you build from the leaves first and then comping up level by level. I also guess the `dag` that you have in the question are not exactly the same as the figure you posted:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
dag = [[5, 4, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 7],
       [], [], [], [1, 3], [1, 2], [0, 2, 3]]
levels = [[8, 9, 10], [0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]


paths = defaultdict(list)
levels_reversed = levels[::-1]

for node in levels_reversed[0]:
    paths[node] = [[node]]

for lvl in levels_reversed[1:]:
    for src in lvl:
        for dst in dag[src-1]:
            paths[src] += [[src] + p for p in paths[dst]]

result = []
for lvl_0 in levels[0]:
    result += paths[lvl_0]
```

Result:

```py
[[8, 1, 5], [8, 1, 4], [8, 1, 6], [8, 1, 7],
 [8, 3, 4], [8, 3, 5], [8, 3, 6], [9, 1, 5],
 [9, 1, 4], [9, 1, 6], [9, 1, 7], [9, 2, 5],
 [9, 2, 6], [9, 2, 7], [10, 2, 5], [10, 2, 6],
 [10, 2, 7], [10, 3, 4], [10, 3, 5], [10, 3, 6]]
```

Comment: I have tested your code (see edit). It's slightly slower than adding a dummy node. Still brilliant answer tho.